# Как оптимальней удалить из списка строки?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТСЯ:** WebDriver, С#

**СЦЕНАРИЙ:**
        1. Переходим на сайт
        2. Парсим список ссылок из элементов страницы по средствам `By.CssSelector(a[href*=ibm])`
        3. Получаем список в котором текстовые поля некоторых позиций пустые (см. скрин).
        4. Удаляем пустые позиции.

Для парсинга использую код
**КОД:**

```
List<IWebElement> link; 
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        link = browser1.FindElements(By.CssSelector(a[href*=ibm])).ToList(); // собираем все ссылки со страницы в список
    }
```

Для удаления пустых позиций использую код
**КОД:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < link.Count; i++) 
{
String c = link[i].Text;  
  if (c.Equals("")) 
   { 
    link.RemoveAt(i);
   }
}
```

Хотел попробовать удаление с помощью RemoveAll,

```
link.RemoveAll("");
```

но выражение в скобках - "" подчёркивается красным и выдаёт ошибку:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'System.Predicate'

**ВОПРОС**
1. Как удалить пустые позиции из списка с помощью "RemoveAll"?
2. Какие есть более эффективные способы для реализации данной задачи (удаление строк из списка по критерию)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод RemoveAll в качестве параметра должен принимать делегат, который возвращает true / false. Мы можем использовать лябда-выражение `параметр => выражение`

```
link.RemoveAll(t => String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text));
```

В данном случае наше лямбда-выражение `t => String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text)` проверит поле `Text` каждого элемента коллекции на null и пустоту и удалит подходящие элементы.

Подробнее про лямбда-выражения [тут](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level10/10_6.php)

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно выбрать заполненные елементы:

```
link = link.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Text)).ToList();
```

Comment: Эх, я опоздал. Ещё лучше сделать это на стадию раньше: `browser1.FindElements(...).Where(...).ToList()`.